# How to show all the lesson urls present in a lesson list?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I would like to retrieve lesson present in chapter model.

```
class Course(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.FloatField()

class Chapter(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField( max_length=200)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Lesson(models.Model):
    chapter = models.ForeignKey(Chapter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    video_url = models.URLField()
```

Below is my views.py:

```
def courseDetail(request, category_slug, course_slug):
    try:
        course_detail = Course.objects.get(category__slug=category_slug, slug=course_slug)
        all_chapters = Chapter.objects.filter(course=course_detail).order_by('created_date')
        all_lessons = Lesson.objects.filter(chapter__id__in=all_chapters)
    except Exception as e:
        raise e

    context = {
        'course_detail': course_detail,
        'all_chapters': all_chapters,
        'all_lessons': all_lessons,
    }
    return render(request, 'course-detail.html', context)
```

Here is my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:category_slug>/<slug:course_slug>/', views.courseDetail, name='course-detail'),
]
```

I am trying to explain my issue with the bellow example
Ex:

1. **Course:** "Course 1"
2. In that course i have 2 chapters i.e Chapter 1, Chapter 2
3. And each chapter contains 3 lessons. i.e Chapter 1 contains Lesson 1, Lesson 2, Lesson 3 and Chapter 2 contains Lesson 4, Lesson 5, Lesson 6.

So when I wanted to show respective lessons inside the respective chapters it's showing all the lessons in both the chapters. How to fix this?

Comment: Could you explain what you would like your "context" dictionary to look like? Your example is helpful, but instead of saying:
"So i am facing the issue while extracting the lesson Urls. Now when i run the above code then its showing. Lesson 1 - (URL1, URL2, URL3, URL4, URL5, URL6) Lesson 2 - (URL1, URL2, URL3, URL4, URL5, URL6)

But I wanted to show like the below: Lesson 1 - (URL1, URL2, URL3) Lesson 2 - (URL4, URL5, URL6)"

I advice you to post what you would like "context" to look like, because that is ultimately the output of your view.

Comment: Thank you @HamsterHooey for your quick response. I will share one image which will illustrate my example. https://prnt.sc/g2wAUxVeZDGE. In this image i wanted to achieve the 1st diagram but getting the 2nd diagram. Let me correct my scenario. My ** Course** contains 2 Chapters (Written Lessons in my question) and Each Chapter contains 3 lessons (written as urls in my question). So when i wanted to show respective lessons inside the respective chapters it's showing all the lessons in both the chapters. That's the problem.

Comment: I mean to say that the lessons are not filtered according to their associated chapters.

Comment: Thanks for the picture. I think you edited the question and now your model names have changed in some places but not in others.

Can you print the value of "context"?

Comment: I changed the model but forgot to update that in views.

Comment: You have no field `slug` in `Course` model, how you are filtering from it?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you want to do but my hunch is replace the following:

```
all_lesson_urls = LessonURL.objects.filter(category__id__in=all_lessons)
```

with

```
all_lesson_urls = LessonURL.objects.filter(category__id__in=all_lessons).values("category__title", "title")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are getting `all_chapters` from `Chapter` model successfully, so to fetch `all_lessons` from `Lesson` model, do this query:

```py
all_chapters = Chapter.objects.filter(course=course_detail).order_by('created_date')
list_of_all_chapters=list(all_chapters)
all_lessons = Lesson.objects.filter(chapter__in=[i.id for i in list_of_all_chapters])
```

> Since [`__in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#in) lookup is used to filter in range of values from list.

Comment: By using the above code Chapter 1: Lesson 1, Lesson 2, Lesson 3 and Chapter 2: Lesson 1, Lesson 2, Lesson 3. But i wanted to show the lessons of respective chapters, not all lessons in both the chapters. i.e. **Chapter 1: Lesson 1, Lesson 2 and Chapter 2: Lesson 3**. Hope i cleared my point.